# Can I center a fixed-height DIV vertically in the viewport with CSS?

Tags: html, css

We have a login page that is designed to have a 200px-high DIV vertically centered in the middle of the page. That is, it creates a 200 pixel blue band left edge to right edge (with form elements in it) that *ideally* should remain vertically centered in the viewport no matter how the browser window is resized.

This must be a CSS solution.

So let's say here's some sample markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
       <div id="centerDiv" style="height:200px;background-color:blue;color:white">
           Center this baby vertically in the #mainDiv, please!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Assume that my CSS dictates that the #mainDiv is stretched to cover the viewport top and bottom, which is easy enough to do. Are there CSS rules that I can apply to any of the elements or the page that will reliably and cross-browser (incl. IE6) vertically center #centerDiv? In a perfect world we should just be able to say

```
#centerDiv {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

And even in an OK world we should be able to address this issue with a few styles. But to quote Ving Rhames' character from Pulp Fiction, We're pretty %&#!ing far from OK.

I've looked at the solutions offered in Related Questions and scoured the Web. Nothing I can find really works 100%. Maybe this is unsolvable, but I thought I'd give the collective brains here the problem and see if I can get lucky. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "no matter how the browser window is resized", do you mean that the div should dynamically re-center itself if the window is resized after the page has been loaded?

Comment: @RegDwight: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a fixed height, you can do it. Give the child div a top of 50% and a margin-top of -100px (or vice-versa) and you should be set.

Comment: Tom, this works great, thanks. I had actually tried a version of this before without success, but when I saw your answer I went back and looked at that code again and found some cruft, including a stray "margin: auto 0" rule, which ruined the whole thing. Once I removed that, it worked. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

if height unknown:

http://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/a7xw6b2c/

```
.centerdiv{
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

}

Comment: this is a good aproach, please don't forget to add `position:absolute;` otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

For true automatic positioning in the center, the inner `DIV` would need to know the boundaries of the containing `DIV`. If your container does not have hard boundaries, there is no way for the inner `DIV` to calculate its own position automatically. It simply has no frame of reference.

The closest I think you can make it with a simple CSS solution is this:

```
    #mainDiv
    {

     border: 1px dashed #000000;   
    }

    #centerDiv
    {
        margin: 33% auto;
        height: 200px;          
    }
```